# How can I keep a .XML file in memory, then save the document to disc as a regular XML file?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, screen-scraping

I'm going to be doing some webscraping and my plan is to have something like this:

```
public class Searcher
{
    public void Search(string searchTerm)
    {
    }

    private void Search(string term)
    { 
        //Some HTMLAgilityPack Voodoo here
    }

    private void SaveResults()
    {
        //Actually save the results as .XML file.
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can keep an .XML file with its contents and everything in memory, and then save the document to disc as a regular XML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either the [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) or [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) classes will allow you to keep XML in memory as XML.

Comment: Which in your opinion is better?

Comment: @Sergio: XDocument and LINQ to XML is much better. `XmlDocument` is the "day 1" XML DOM implementation.

Comment: XDocument is newer, and if you're comfortable with LINQ, you'll probably find it easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

Look into XDocument.Load and XDocument.Save with LINQ to XML if you're using .NET 3.5+